# How to change field attributes of Content Entity?

Tags: 8, entities

In a custom module, I have a content entity in which I have defined this field:

```
$fields['formheader'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
  ->setLabel(t('Header'))
  ->setSettings([
    'max_length' => 255,
    'text_processing' => 0,
  ])
  ->setDefaultValue('')
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'string',
    'weight' => $weight,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'string_textfield',
    'weight' => $weight,
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

I'd like to change its type from string to string_long and max_length from 255 to 1024.
How can I do that without uninstalling my module, changing my source code and installing my module again (there is already content in this entity)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally with help from Jdrupal and this [article](https://www.drupal.org/node/2535476), I made it work:

```
function amap_update_8001(&$sandbox)
{
  $entity_type_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
  $bundle_of = 'contract_type';

  $storage = $entity_type_manager->getStorage($bundle_of);
  $bundle_definition = $entity_type_manager->getDefinition($bundle_of);
//Sometimes the primary key isn't 'id'. e.g. 'eid' or 'item_id'.
  $id_key = $bundle_definition->getKey('id');
//If there is no data table defined then use the base table.
  $table_name = $storage->getDataTable() ?: $storage->getBaseTable();
  $database = \Drupal::database();
  $definition_manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();

//Store the existing values.
  $header_values = $database->select($table_name)
    ->fields($table_name, [$id_key, 'formheader'])
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAllAssoc($id_key);

//Clear out the values.
  $database->update($table_name)
    ->fields(['formheader' => NULL])
    ->execute();

//Uninstall the field.
  $field_storage_definition = $definition_manager->getFieldStorageDefinition('formheader', $bundle_of);
  $definition_manager->uninstallFieldStorageDefinition($field_storage_definition);

//Create a new field definition.
  $new_formheader = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string_long')
    ->setLabel(t('Header for Form'))
    ->setSettings([
      'max_length' => 1024,
      'text_processing' => 0,
    ])
    ->setDefaultValue('')
    ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
      'label' => 'above',
      'type' => 'string_long',
    ])
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
      'type' => 'string_textarea',
    ])
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

//Install the new definition.
  $definition_manager->installFieldStorageDefinition('formheader', $bundle_of, $bundle_of, $new_formheader);

//Restore the values.
  foreach ($header_values as $id => $value) {
    $database->update($table_name)
      ->fields(['formheader' => $value->formheader])
      ->condition($id_key, $id)
      ->execute();
  }

  drupal_flush_all_caches();

  \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('Module AMAP Update # 8001 was executed successfully.');

}
```